xml update with current category variable
How can I insert "currentcategory" variable instead of 504 in category_ids ?
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>

        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block name="Babygear\Categoryslider\Block\ProductSlider" template="Magento_Catalog::product/slider/product-slider.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="category_ids" xsi:type="string">504</argument>
                    <argument name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Our favorites in Red</argument>
                    <argument name="sort_attribute" xsi:type="string">default</argument>
                    <argument name="sort_direction" xsi:type="string">DESC</argument>
                    <argument name="hide_rating_summary" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
                    <argument name="hide_details" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>

